# Which numpy versions are compatible with Tensorflow 1.14.0

Tags: tensorflow

I'm getting warnings combining 1.14.0 with numpy 1.17.2.  Do these go together?  I can't find any official TF page stating compatibility requirements.

Comment: What sort of warnings?

Comment: Like here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31249

Comment: You can run `pip3 show tensorflow` to see its version and other information

Answer (score 5):

Please downgrade `numpy` version from `1.17.2` to `1.16.4` will resolve issue with `Tensorflow 1.14.0`

Here am able to replicate issue

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])

1.14.0
1.17.2
```

To fix this, please execute below code to downgrade `numpy` to `1.16.4`

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.16.4
```

After that, please restart your runtime and execute below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

Output:

```
1.14.0
1.16.4
```

Comment: I did not do `pip uninstall numpy`, rather directly ran `pip install numpy==1.16.4`. Seemed to work

Answer (score 2):

Those who are looking for tensorflow2 and numpy compatible versions. They work fine together.

```
Tensorflow 2.4.1
numpy 1.19.5
```

Comment: Where/What is the documentation/command specifying which versions of numpy tensorflow x supports?